# Visible nth child on each click - missing something

Tags: jquery

I'm really close with this but am missing something to get it to work right. I've set up  a [test page here](http://420dev.com/_lab/).

When hovering over the first filters group and click on Naming & Voice, it filters properly and the margins on the image placeholders are all correct. If you then click on Digital (without resetting the filter), the filter still works but the margins are messed up so that the first row only has 3 images instead of 4.

I'm not sure what I need to add to the code to get the margins to be set correctly each time the set is filtered through. Or more specifically, have it set so that every fourth item is getting no margin.

Here's the JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){



//WORK OVERVIEW FILTERS
$('.nav-secondary.filters .section-inner').each(function(){
    //NAV REVEAL ON HOVER
    var conf = {
        over: function() {
            $(this).find('ul.filter-list,.reset').slideDown(250,'swing');
        },
        timeout: 25,
        out: function() {
            $(this).find('ul.filter-list,.reset').slideUp(250,'swing');
        }
    }
    $(this).hoverIntent(conf);

    //FILTER FUNCTIONS
    var _filter = '';
    var _count = 0;
    $('a.work-filter').click(function(){
        _filter = $(this).data('filter');

        $('.item.work[data-cats*="'+_filter+'"]').each(function(){
            $(this).show(250,'swing');
        });

        $('.item.work:not([data-cats*="'+_filter+'"])').each(function(){
            $(this).hide(250,'swing');
        });


        $('.item.work[data-cats*="'+_filter+'"]:visible').each(function (i) {
            if ((i+1) % 4 == 0) $(this).css('margin-right', '0');
        });





        $('a.work-filter.active').removeClass('active').data('active','no');
        $(this).addClass('active').data('active','yes');
        $('ul.work-filters').find('a.parent.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).closest('ul').siblings('a.parent').addClass('current');

    });

    $('.reset a').click(function(){
        $('.item.work').each(function(){
            $(this).show(250,'swing');
        });
        $('a.work-filter.active').removeClass('active').data('active','no');
        $('ul.work-filters').find('a.parent.current').removeClass('current');
    });

});



});
```

**EDIT:** To clarify, when you first click the filter, it works as it should. It's any subsequent clicking that the margin doesn't get removed in the right spots. So what's missing is some way to clear it all out again and the reapply the margin-right:0 when any filters are clicked after the first.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to set all .active in their own array/object and count them from there for margins, as right now, all images are being counted, including "display:none"s, and therefore rules appear to be applied haphazardly.

Comment: Now that I've read this a few more times, not all the images are being counted - the (i+1) % 4 bit takes care of that. It's on going from the first filter to the next where the margins aren't getting cleared properly as the previously set margins are kept instead of reset.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reset `margin-right` for all elements on each filtering:

```
if ((i+1) % 4 == 0) $(this).css('margin-right', '0');
else $(this).css('margin-right', '8px');
```

Answer (score 0):

So I couldn't get this working via JS/jQuery. Instead, I widened the containing div to not worry about the extra margin on the 4th element.